# Method 'get_IsWildCardPath' failure during app start

Tags: servicestack

I have started getting the following error in my AppHost Class when the base class is invoked: Method 'get_IsWildCardPath' in type 'ServiceStack.ServiceHost.RestPath' from assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=3.9.49.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

This site has been working for months on my workstation and stopped working a few days ago. I have tried copying all directories from another machine that this site works on but I still get this error.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you updated your NuGet packages lately? `IsWildCardPath` became a public property on `RestPath` [relatively recently](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/28ff7d806240d9b2fae0e576bc75c7530fa81497). Perhaps there was a package upgrade that only got applied to some of your ServiceStack packages. Try checking the version numbers of all the ServiceStack assembly references.